# Python "denormalize" unicode combining characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm looking to standardize some unicode text in python. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to get the "denormalized" form of a combining unicode character in python? e.g. if I have the sequence `u'o\xaf'` (i.e. `latin small letter o` followed by `combining macron`), to get ō (`latin small letter o with macron`). It's easy to go the other way:

```
o = unicodedata.lookup("LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON")
o = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', o)
```

Comment: U+00AF is not a *combining* macron. That is U+0304.

Comment: `\xaf` isn't the combining macron, `\u0304` is.

Comment: oops. Got the numbers mixed up when I wrote the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have commented, U+00AF is not a combining macron. But you can convert it into U+0020 U+0304 with an NFKD transform.

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'o\u00af')
u'o \u0304'
```

Then you could remove the space and get ō with NFC.

---

(Note that NFKD is quite aggressive on decomposition in a way that some semantics can be lost — anything that is "compatible" will be separated out. e.g.

- `'½'` (U+008D) ↦ `'1'` `'⁄'` (U+2044) `'2'`;
- `'²'` (U+00B2) ↦ `'2'`
- `'①'` (U+2460) ↦ `'1'`

etc.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks - I'd tried NFKD, but I didn't think of re-normalizing it again.

Comment: Given the fact that the string the question meant to specify as the input was `u'o\u0304'` there's no need for NFKD normalisation first.  Performing just NFC normalisation on that string is enough to get desired result of `u'\u014d'`.

Comment: @markshep: Please careful read OP's question, the input sequence was `u'o\xaf'` i.e. "o¯", **not** `u'o\u0304'`. You need to do NFKD to convert the `'\xaf'` into `' \u0304'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
o = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', o)
```