# Trouble reading string with non-ascii characters in python 3

Tags: python, string, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode, file-not-found

I am trying to read images from WikiArt dataset. However, I cannot load some images which contain non-ascii characters:
For example:
**fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'**
although the file exists in the directory.
I also compared the output string name from `os.listdir()` and the one from `FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/wiki_art_paintings/rescaled_600px_max_side/Expressionism/fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'`
by doing
`'fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg' == 'fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'`. The output is **False**.

What can be a problem here?

Comment: Please add your code and a proper output of the error traceback

Comment: did you check char-by-char what codes have chars? you could write script to do this. Maybe you have two chars which look the same but they have different code. or maybe there is code which is not displayed on screen.

Comment: when I check char-by-char then it shows me `ã` as two chars `a ̃ ` - In unicode it is possible

Comment: @furas, yeah, how can I fix it?

Comment: how do you get these files? Maybe it could be corrected when you get files and put on disk. And what system do you use? Maybe problem makes system - once I had problem with MacOS because it was using UTF-8 in different standard.

Comment: @furas, I have several image folders and csv file which contains some data + reference to the images in those folders as string

Comment: I found only old code which test different method to convert MacOS filenames in Unicode to Linux Unicode [macosx-linux-UTF-8](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/decode-encode/macosx-linux/main.py) Using function `unidecode()` I can conver both versions to the same `fa(c)lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg` so they can be compared (`==` will gives `True`) but it is still useless to get name from file and create filename to open image.

Comment: Seams to be related to normalized/denormalized forms. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126929/python-denormalize-unicode-combining-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because in `Unicode` you can use single character or create some character as combinations of two other charactes and you have both situations in two different places. In one place you have some characters as single characters (with single code) and in other place you have characters as combinatins of two other characters (with two codes). You can see even difference when you use `len()` for boths strings. In your example one version has lenght `53` and other has `52`

It seems you could convert one name to another using `unicodedata.normalize()` with one of option `NFC`, `NFKC`, `NFD`, `NFKD`. So you have to test which one will work for you.

In one direction you may need `NFC` or `NFKC`, in other direction you may need `NFD` or `NFKD`.

You can also use `unidecode` to create text without native characters: `fa(c)lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg` but this may not be so useful for you.

```
import unicodedata
from unidecode import unidecode

a = 'fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'
b = 'fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'

print('a:', a)
print('b:', b)

print('--- len ---')
print('len(a):', len(a))
print('len(b):', len(b))

print('--- encode ---')
print('a.encode:', a.encode('utf-8'))
print('b.encode:', b.encode('utf-8'))

print('--- a == normalize(b) ---')
print('NFC: ', a == unicodedata.normalize('NFC', b) )
print('NFKC:', a == unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', b) )
print('NFD: ', a == unicodedata.normalize('NFD', b) )
print('NFKD:', a == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', b) )

print('--- b == normalize(a) ---')
print('NFC: ', b == unicodedata.normalize('NFC', a) )
print('NFKC:', b == unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', a) )
print('NFD: ', b == unicodedata.normalize('NFD', a) )
print('NFKD:', b == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', a) )

print('--- unidecode ---')
print('a:', unidecode(a))
print('b:', unidecode(b))
```

Result:

```
a: fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg
b: fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg
--- len ---
len(a): 53
len(b): 52
--- encode ---
a.encode: b'fa\xcc\x83\xc2\xa9lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'
b.encode: b'f\xc3\xa3\xc2\xa9lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'
--- a == normalize(b) ---
NFC:  False
NFKC: False
NFD:  True
NFKD: True
--- b == normalize(a) ---
NFC:  True
NFKC: True
NFD:  False
NFKD: False
--- unidecode ---
a: fa(c)lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg
b: fa(c)lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg
```

---

I met characters as combination of two other characters only when I have to transfer MacOS files to other system

---

Doc: [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html)

Pythonsheet: [Unicode](https://www.pythonsheets.com/notes/python-unicode.html)

Stackoverflow: [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

Comment: thank you, @furas. Simply introducing normalization helped me to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

The two strings are not the same. Look:

```
> ciao='fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'.encode('utf-8')       
> bye='fã©lix-del-marle_nu-agenouill-sur-fond-bleu-1937.jpg'.encode('utf-8')        
> ciao.hex() 
 '6661cc83c2a96c69782d64656c2d6d61726c655f6e752d6167656e6f75696c6c2d7375722d666f6e642d626c65752d313933372e6a7067'
> bye.hex()  
 '66c3a3c2a96c69782d64656c2d6d61726c655f6e752d6167656e6f75696c6c2d7375722d666f6e642d626c65752d313933372e6a7067'
> ciao2='fa'.encode('utf-8')
> bye2='f'.encode('utf-8')
> ciao2.hex()
 '6661'
> bye2.hex() 
 '66'
```

it seems there is an hidden character around the 'f'. It seems a 'a'

Comment: nice description but it is place for solutions and I don't see any solution in your answer

Comment: The problem is that your filename contains é. The process that created  the file wrote out the name in UTF-8 which needs 2 bytes to represent é. Your filesystem doesn't understand UTF-8 so it is displaying the 2 bytes as if it were encoded as latin-1. Try putting é in the filename in your call to `open()` instead of ã©.